# Time series analysis if it is predictable or not

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictive-models

I have two types of time series, stationary time series dataset and non stationary time series dataset. Now I need to know if these two series predictable or not. I read about the models of predictability and the measure of predictability like mean ,RMSE,...
But really I am very confuse because I do not know how to know if the series is predictable or not.

Answer (score 2):

Both are predictable, just not equally well. Consider a simple nonstationary random walk
$$
y_t=y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t=y_0+\sum_{j=1}^t\epsilon_j
$$
Suppose we observe this process until $T$ and want to forecast $h$ periods ahead. Write
$$
y_{T+h}=y_T+\sum_{j=1}^{T+h}\epsilon_j
$$
Then, since the errors are mean zero, our best forecast, for *any horizon* $h$, simply is $y_T$, the last observed value. In that sense, the process is "predictable". However, the forecast error variance $Var(\sum_{j=1}^{T+h}\epsilon_j)=h\sigma^2$ will increase without bound in $h$, which is not generally the case for a stationary process.

Comment: Thanks, @ChristophHanck, Is that mean that the result depends on the value of forecast error or RMSE, for example, if the value of (RMSE > 0) that means the series is not predictable. if( RMSE <=0) that means the series is predictable. Is that correct?

Comment: No. RMSE stands for root mean squared error, so, being the square root of a square, is always nonnegative. RMSE is to be interpreted as: the lower it is, the better the forecast model can forecast a series.

Comment: Yes that right, because I have square root of a square so it is always  positive.I use autoregression model (AR), the result for series1 : Test RMSE: 0.017
and for series2 : Test RMSE: 7.725
Now can I say series1  is predictable?

Comment: The RMSE depends on the scale of your data. Divide each historical and future observation by 10, then you will get the exact same model except for the intercept, and the RMSE will also be 10 times smaller. That does not mean your series now is "10 times more predictable". There are various technical definitions of predictability out there, I assume you are not using one of those (otherwise please tell us). You need to tell us what your definition of "predictability" is, otherwise your question cannot be answered.

Comment: To put Stephan's comment a little differently, RMSE is more useful to compare two (or more) models (e.g., an AR(1) and an MA(1)) for a given single series to see which model is more useful to predict that series.

Comment: According to this https://pkghosh.wordpress.com/2020/01/21/evaluation-of-time-series-predictability-with-kaboudan-metric-using-prophet/ A time series is predictable when there is strong correlation between past data and present data. If you get large error from a time series forecasting model, it could because of any of the following reasons

-Wrong model
-Not properly tuned for the model
-The time series is inherently unpredictable